# COS is running out of inodes for /var/lib/docker volume

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-container-os

I'm trying to us cos to run some services on GCP.

One of the issues I'm seeing currently is that the VMs I've started very quickly seem to run out of inodes for the /var/lib/docker filesystem. I'd have expected this to be one of the things tuned in a container optimized os?

`wouter@nbwm-cron ~ $ df -hi
Filesystem            Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/root                78K   13K   65K   17% /
devtmpfs                463K   204  463K    1% /dev
tmpfs                   464K     1  464K    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   464K   500  463K    1% /run
tmpfs                   464K    13  464K    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                   464K     9  464K    1% /mnt/disks
tmpfs                   464K   16K  448K    4% /tmp
/dev/sda8               4.0K    11  4.0K    1% /usr/share/oem
/dev/sda1              1013K  998K   15K   99% /var
tmpfs                   464K    45  464K    1% /var/lib/cloud
overlayfs               464K    39  464K    1% /etc`

`wouter@nbwm-cron ~ $ docker images
REPOSITORY                                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<name>/stackdriver-agent                latest              0c4b075e7550        3 days ago          1.423 GB
<none>                                    <none>              96d027d3feea        4 days ago          905.2 MB
gcr.io/<project>/nbwm-ops/docker-php5   latest              5d2c59c7dd7a        2 weeks ago         1.788 GB`

`nbwm-cron wouter # tune2fs -l /dev/sda1
tune2fs 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
Filesystem volume name:   STATE
Last mounted on:          /var
Filesystem UUID:          ca44779b-ffd5-405a-bd3e-528071b45f73
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Remount read-only
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              1036320
Block count:              4158971
Reserved block count:     0
Free blocks:              4062454
Free inodes:              1030756
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Reserved GDT blocks:      747
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8160
Inode blocks per group:   510
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Thu Jun 15 22:39:33 2017
Last mount time:          Wed Jun 28 13:51:31 2017
Last write time:          Wed Jun 28 13:51:31 2017
Mount count:              5
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Thu Nov 19 19:00:00 2009
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          67 MB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      66aa0e7f-57da-41d0-86f7-d93270e53030
Journal backup:           inode blocks`

How do I tune the filesystem to have more inodes available?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the `overlay` storage driver in docker and is addressed by the `overlay2` driver.
The new cos-61 [releases](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/release-notes) use docker 17.03 with `overlay2` storage driver. Could you please give it a try and see if the issue happens again?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a recent COS version is not enough, GKE 1.9+ is required too (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45759459/316805).

Answer (score 1):

I have witnessed the same issue with all COS versions from `57.9202.64.0` (docker `1.11.2`) on GKE 1.5 to `65.10323.85.0` (docker `17.03.2`) on GKE `1.8.12-gke.1`. Older version were certainly affected too.

Those all use the `overlay` driver:

```
pdecat@gke-cluster-test-pdecat-default-pool-e8945081-xhj6 ~ $ docker info 2>&1 | grep "Storage Driver"
Storage Driver: overlay

pdecat@gke-cluster-test-pdecat-default-pool-e8945081-xhj6 ~ $ grep "\(CHROMEOS_RELEASE_VERSION\|CHROMEOS_RELEASE_CHROME_MILESTONE\)" /etc/lsb-release
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_CHROME_MILESTONE=65
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_VERSION=10323.85.0
```

The `overlay2` driver is only used for GKE 1.9+ clusters (fresh or upgraded) with the same COS version:

```
pdecat@gke-cluster-test-pdecat-default-pool-e8945081-xhj6 ~ $ docker info 2>&1 | grep "Storage Driver"
Storage Driver: overlay2

pdecat@gke-cluster-test-pdecat-default-pool-e8945081-xhj6 ~ $ grep "\(CHROMEOS_RELEASE_VERSION\|CHROMEOS_RELEASE_CHROME_MILESTONE\)" /etc/lsb-release
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_CHROME_MILESTONE=65
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_VERSION=10323.85.0
```

When the free space/inodes issue occurs with the `overlay` driver, I resolve it using spotify's docker-gc:

```
# docker run --rm --userns host -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /etc:/etc spotify/docker-gc
```

Before:

```
# df -hi /var/lib/docker/
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        6.0M  5.0M  1.1M   83% /var

# df -h /var/lib/docker/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        95G   84G   11G  89% /var

# du --inodes -s /var/lib/docker/*
180     /var/lib/docker/containers
4093    /var/lib/docker/image
4       /var/lib/docker/network
4906733 /var/lib/docker/overlay
1       /var/lib/docker/tmp
1       /var/lib/docker/trust
25      /var/lib/docker/volumes
```

After:

```
# df -hi /var/lib/docker/
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        6.0M  327K  5.7M    6% /var/lib/docker

# df -h /var/lib/docker/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        95G  6.6G   88G   7% /var/lib/docker

# du --inodes -s /var/lib/docker/*
218     /var/lib/docker/containers
1792    /var/lib/docker/image
4       /var/lib/docker/network
279002  /var/lib/docker/overlay
1       /var/lib/docker/tmp
1       /var/lib/docker/trust
25      /var/lib/docker/volumes
```

Note: using the usual `docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)` and `docker rm $(docker ps -qa --no-trunc --filter "status=exited")` did not help to recover resources in `/var/lib/docker/overlay`.